# Saving boto3 output to JSON

Tags: python, json, boto3

Need to save boto3 output (as a backup) to JSON file

```
#!/bin/python

import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('iam')
response = client.get_account_authorization_details(

)

sys.stdout = open('output.json','wt')

print response
```

i got output:

```
{u'RoleDetailList': [{u'AssumeRolePolicyDocument': {u'Version': u
```

How can i get rid of `u` ?

and also i can't parse this output:

```
with open('output.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)


    ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

tried:

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(response, outfile)
```

now getting:`TypeError: datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 20, 13, 51, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable`

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to remove the unicode encode, Can you just use json.dump(dictionary_obj, file_obj)

Comment: why are you overwriting the `sys` variable

Comment: i'm new to python and found on the net syntax to save output to file

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would properly do it, in the most simple basic way

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('ec2')

resp = client.describe_regions()

{u'Regions': [{u'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
   u'RegionName': 'ap-south-1'},
  {u'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com', u'RegionName': 'eu-west-3'},
  {u'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com', u'RegionName': 'eu-west-2'},
  {u'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', u'RegionName': 'eu-west-1'},
  {u'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com',
....

with open('random.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(resp, fout)


c = json.load(open('random.json', 'r'))

{u'Regions': [{u'Endpoint': u'ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
   u'RegionName': u'ap-south-1'},
  {u'Endpoint': u'ec2.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com', u'RegionName': u'eu-west-3'},
  {u'Endpoint': u'ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com', u'RegionName': u'eu-west-2'},
  {u'Endpoint': u'ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', u'RegionName': u'eu-west-1'},
  {u'Endpoint': u'ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

this solved my issue, thanks everyone:

```
#!/bin/python

import boto3
import json
from bson import json_util

client = boto3.client('iam')

response = client.get_account_authorization_details(

)

with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(response, outfile, default=json_util.default)
```